# Jira integration in Backstage giving 404 error

Tags: annotations, jira, jira-plugin, backstage

I'm currently testing Backstage for my company, and I tried various continuous integration pipelines like Github, Jira, Jenkins, and more. But I'm facing an issue with the Jira plugin. Maybe it's just a bad setup.

In my component, I can see the Jira entity, but every time, it says:

```
failed to fetch data, status 404: Not Found
```

When I look in the browser's console (network), I can see this 404, and this is the query used:

```
http://localhost:7007/api/proxy/jira/api/rest/api/latest/project/undefined
```

Why do I have `undefined`? Is it because the `jira/project-key` variable is not at the right place? Actually, it's in the `catalog-info.yaml` under metadata.

I followed all documentation I could find, but one section is not enough clear for me. It's about the annotations thing. It says `Add annotation to the yaml config file of a component. I created a component yesterday, but I don't see any file for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution.

In the documentation, the file, called catalog-info.yaml, is not the one at the Backstage repository's root, but to a file in a different repository that will be used as component template in Backstage.

If you create a new repository (ex a fork from Symfony), you will have to add the file catalog-info.yaml with various informations if you want to use this repository as template for your projects.